# Update Bootstrap Carousel First Slider Timing (Starting Time of Slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my Bootstrap carousel, first image slider takes more time to start the sliding images i.e. slider staring time is low.

I have updated slide item timing too, but it works good on slide timing.

```
.carousel-inner>.item {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out left;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out left
}
```

Where can I update timing for quick start of Bootstrap Carousel. I am using Bootstrap v3.1.1.